# Having Some Issues with If condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to send an email if someone register their attendance before and after the set time.

The office starts at 8:30 am but I'm having an issue with hours and minutes. the email triggers  as late even if the time is 7:45 am , where did I go wrong?

```
var startTime = mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getDisplayValue();
var OfficeStart = mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getValue();
var officehour = OfficeStart.getHours();
var officemin = OfficeStart.getMinutes();
if (officehour >= 08 || officemin >=30){
var startTime = startTime+ "<font color='Red'> ⬤ Late </font>";
}
else{
var StartTime =startTime +"<font color='Green'> ⬤ OnTime </font>";
}
```

Comment: `console.log(officehour, officemin)` and confirm they are the values you expect.  Also `08` should just be `8`

Comment: `45` is `>= 30`

Comment: why dont you compare the whole date instead on hours and minutes?

Comment: You must not check hours and minutes independently. So do: `if (officehour * 100 + +officemin >= 830) {`

Comment: to check whether two dates fall exactly at the same time, you can check their timestamps with getTime

Comment: @trincot Your solution worked :D Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this condition:

```
if (officehour >= 08 || officemin >=30){
```

Even if the first part of the condition is false, the second part can still be true, and that makes the whole expression true. So concretely, if the minutes-part of the time is 30 or more, then the condition is true, no matter what the hours part is. Similarly, if the hours part is 8 or more, then the condition is true, no matter what the minutes part is.

You need to look at the whole time indication at once, and see whether it comes before 8:30 or not. One way is to convert the time components to a 4 digit number (hhmm) and compare that:

```
if (officehour * 100 + +officemin >= 830) {
```

Note that the `+` before `officemin` is a unary plus, which converts `officemin` to number in case it was a string. If `officehour` is a string, it already gets converted to number by the multiplication.

Comment: Your solution worked :D Thank you very much, I was a bit confused and puzzled about what is happening... LOL but I now completely understood what went wrong. The hour and minutes checking independently and not together. Thank you for your great point. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd follow J. G.'s advice and cast to a date but the reason you are not getting the result you expect is because your if condition isn't right.

`officehour >= 08 || officemin >=30` is true if officehour is 8 or above or if officemin is 30 or above.

Here's a truth table

```
| Officehour | Officemin   |officehour >= 08 | officemin >=30 | result  |
|:----------:|:-----------:|:---------------:|:--------------:|:--------|
| 7          |        45   |    false        |  true          | true    |
| 8          |        15   |    true         |  false         | true    |
| 7          |        15   |    false        |  false         | false   |
```

You probably want something more along the lines of

```
(officeHour > 8 || (officeHour == 8 && officemin > 30))
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try casting your office start to a date first.

```
var OfficeStart = new Date(mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getValue());
```

If that doesn't work add this line for troubleshooting to the end

```
console.log("%s : %s",officehour, officemin);
```